# I need to make a the subject in\int_0^{2\pi b}a^2b^2(\(sin(bx))^2+1)\mathrm dx

Tags: calculus, elliptic-integrals

I need to find a function whose arguments are the period of a $\sin$ function and its arc length, and whose output is the height a of the $\sin$ function.
In my physical system I need to make a thing which is of given arc length, and what I need to know is the coefficient $a$ in $a\cos(x)$, for a complete cycle of $\cos$ from $0...2\pi$, to satisfy the arc length requirement.

Edit:
My physical system contains lines described by $a\sin(bx)$. I need to set $a$ to keep arc length = $2\pi$, for $b<1$ or $b=1$
Attempting to use the Arc Length Formula, I arrived at $$\int_{0}^{2\pi}\sqrt{1+a^2 b^2 \cos^2 (bx)}\,dx$$
My phone is not the ideal instrument on which to learn MathJax well enough to edit my question. Thank you for your patience. Surely there is a better way than fumbling with LaTex on an iphone.

Thank you very much
Mark

Comment: Do you mean this? $$\int_0^{2\pi b}a^2b^2(\sin(bx)+1)\mathrm dx$$

Comment: No not quite right. How can I formulate it correctly... the 1+ (...) all needs a square root. Thanks John Doe :)

Comment: This integral can be evaluated. $$a^2b^2\left[x-\frac1b\cos(bx)\right]_0^{2\pi b}=a^2b^2\left(2\pi b-\frac1{\cos(2b^2\pi)}+\frac1b\right)$$ It isn't clear to me what you are asking in your question, though.

Comment: Whoops sorry but thanks... I hope I’ve clarified properly :)

Comment: Ahh you mean it should be $\sqrt{\sin(bx)+1}$ then? That should be more challenging... Or do you mean just the $\sin$? So $(1+\sqrt{\sin(bx)})$

Comment: So integral(sqrt(22(sin()+1))dx is wanted

Comment: almost the first, more challenging one, but worse. The (a*b*sin(x)) should be all squared

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). Use that next time you ask a question, it'll make things much clearer.

Answer (score 1):

Your integral is equivalent to $$ab\int_0^{2\pi b}\sqrt{(\sin(bx)+1)}\mathrm dx$$Make a substitution $y=bx$. $$a\int_0^{2\pi b^2}\sqrt{\sin(y)+1}\mathrm dy $$Use $\sin(y)=\cos(\pi/2 - y)$ and $\cos\theta=2\cos^2(\theta/2)-1$. This gives $$a\int_0^{2\pi b^2}\sqrt2\cos\left(\frac\pi4-\frac y2\right)\mathrm dy=-a\sqrt2\left(\sin\left(\frac\pi4-\pi b^2\right)-\sin\frac\pi4\right)=a\sqrt2\left(\frac1{\sqrt2}-\frac1{\sqrt2}\cos(\pi b^2)+\frac1{\sqrt2}\sin(\pi b^2)\right)=a(1-\cos(\pi b^2)+\sin(\pi b^2))$$

Comment: Thank you so much! I’ll study the given answer as soon as I can do so... not on my phone!